# What object does ENV return in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

There's an ENV variable we all know. It returns an Object. But the return value of ENV is visually similar to a Hash. But it's really not.

For example:

```
> ENV
=> {"SHELL"=>"/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER"=>"local/archlinux:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/613,unix/archlinux:/tmp/.ICE-unix/613", "COLORTERM"=>"truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"=>"/etc/xdg", "XDG_MENU_PREFIX"=>"xfce-", "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"=>"/tmp/ssh-Al0pdO1R5970/agent.622", "DESKTOP_SESSION"=>"Xfce Session", "SSH_AGENT_PID"=>"623", "GTK_MODULES"=>"canberra-gtk-module:canberra-gtk-module", "XDG_SEAT"=>"seat0", "PWD"=>"/home/sourav", "LOGNAME"=>"sourav", "XDG_SESSION_TYPE"=>"x11", "XAUTHORITY"=>"/home/sourav/.Xauthority", "HOME"=>"/home/sourav", "LANG"=>"en_GB.UTF-8", "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"=>"XFCE", "VTE_VERSION"=>"5603", "INVOCATION_ID"=>"6d4dc7a91cc141e691436cb850e18f8d", "GLADE_CATALOG_PATH"=>":", "XDG_SESSION_CLASS"=>"user", "TERM"=>"xterm-256color", "USER"=>"sourav", "DISPLAY"=>":0.0", "SHLVL"=>"2", "XDG_VTNR"=>"1", "XDG_SESSION_ID"=>"1", "TILIX_ID"=>"f2480263-263e-408f-be36-8105e71256a6", "MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH"=>"/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins", "GLADE_MODULE_PATH"=>":", "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"=>"/run/user/1000", "GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH"=>":", "JOURNAL_STREAM"=>"9:25041", "XDG_DATA_DIRS"=>"/usr/local/share:/usr/share", "PATH"=>"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sourav/.rvm/bin:/home/sourav/.rvm/bin:/home/sourav/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin", "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"=>"unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus", "MAIL"=>"/var/spool/mail/sourav", "_"=>"/home/sourav/.irb", "LINES"=>"24", "COLUMNS"=>"80"}
```

Which looks similar to:

```
> ENV.to_h
=> {"SHELL"=>"/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER"=>"local/archlinux:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/613,unix/archlinux:/tmp/.ICE-unix/613", "COLORTERM"=>"truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"=>"/etc/xdg", "XDG_MENU_PREFIX"=>"xfce-", "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"=>"/tmp/ssh-Al0pdO1R5970/agent.622", "DESKTOP_SESSION"=>"Xfce Session", "SSH_AGENT_PID"=>"623", "GTK_MODULES"=>"canberra-gtk-module:canberra-gtk-module", "XDG_SEAT"=>"seat0", "PWD"=>"/home/sourav", "LOGNAME"=>"sourav", "XDG_SESSION_TYPE"=>"x11", "XAUTHORITY"=>"/home/sourav/.Xauthority", "HOME"=>"/home/sourav", "LANG"=>"en_GB.UTF-8", "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"=>"XFCE", "VTE_VERSION"=>"5603", "INVOCATION_ID"=>"6d4dc7a91cc141e691436cb850e18f8d", "GLADE_CATALOG_PATH"=>":", "XDG_SESSION_CLASS"=>"user", "TERM"=>"xterm-256color", "USER"=>"sourav", "DISPLAY"=>":0.0", "SHLVL"=>"2", "XDG_VTNR"=>"1", "XDG_SESSION_ID"=>"1", "TILIX_ID"=>"f2480263-263e-408f-be36-8105e71256a6", "MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH"=>"/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins", "GLADE_MODULE_PATH"=>":", "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"=>"/run/user/1000", "GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH"=>":", "JOURNAL_STREAM"=>"9:25041", "XDG_DATA_DIRS"=>"/usr/local/share:/usr/share", "PATH"=>"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sourav/.rvm/bin:/home/sourav/.rvm/bin:/home/sourav/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin", "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"=>"unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus", "MAIL"=>"/var/spool/mail/sourav", "_"=>"/home/sourav/.irb", "LINES"=>"24", "COLUMNS"=>"80"}
```

But:

```
> ENV.to_h.eql?(ENV)
=> false
```

So what kind of object does ENV return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a custom Object with Hash-like functionality mostly implemented in C.

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L4944

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the Ruby Language Specification that requires `ENV` to be implemented in any particular way. As long as it responds to the right messages in the right way, it can be anything it wants.

For example, in Rubinius, `ENV` is implemented in a class called `Rubinius::EnvironmentVariables` that implements part of the `Hash` protocol and also mixes in `Enumerable`: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/env.rb .